# How should I read self-closing XML tags using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am reading some XML using PHP, but I can't figure out how to read self-closing tags. I have `<No_of_Rooms/>` tags which sometime present themselves as `<No_of_Rooms>3</No_of_Rooms>`, and sometimes as `<No_of_Rooms/>`.
What's the right way to read these?

This is the code I'm currently using.

```
$rooms_tag = $property->getElementsByTagName("No_of_Rooms");
$exists = $rooms_tag->length > 0;
if (!$exists ) 
    $rooms=0;
else    
    $rooms = $rooms_tag->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo "Number of rooms   : " . $rooms . "<br>";
```

Here is an example of the XML environment:

```
<property>
  <Unit_Reference_No>EL-S-1028</Unit_Reference_No>
  <No_of_Rooms/>
  <Latitude>25.198519</Latitude>
  <Longitude>55.275478</Longitude>
  <unit_measure>Sq.Ft.</unit_measure>
</property>
```

Comment: What do you want to do, show `0 rooms` if it doesn't have a value?

Comment: Does you XML contains only single <No_of_rooms> element?

Comment: Can you show us the XML?

Comment: <property>
     <Unit_Reference_No>EL-S-1028</Unit_Reference_No>
     <No_of_Rooms/>
     <Latitude>25.198519</Latitude>
     <Longitude>55.275478</Longitude>
     <unit_measure>Sq.Ft.</unit_measure>
     </property>

Comment: [`intval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will always return a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the element's nodeValue isn't an empty string.  The nodeValue of a DOMNode is a string and if there is no value set you will get an empty string when you look at any DOMNode->nodeValue property.

I was able to get your XML + code working by changing your check on line 2 to `$exists = $rooms_tag->item(0)->nodeValue != '';`

I think you may also be confusing yourself with the way you name your variables.  `getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList` object, which (potentially) holds multiple `DOMNode` objects.  The length of the $rooms_tag `NodeList` will always be > 0 if you have a single No_of_Rooms element in your XML.  If I were to rewrite all of that it would look like this:

```
$rooms_list = $property->getElementsByTagName("No_of_Rooms");
$rooms_tag = $rooms_list->item(0); //or loop through the list if you expect multiple items.

//if nodeValue has a value, set $num_rooms to that value, else set it to 0.
$num_rooms = ($rooms_tag->nodeValue != '' ? $rooms_tag->nodeValue : 0);
echo "Number of rooms   : " . $num_rooms . "<br>";}
```

This is (to me anyway) much more clear.